# Getting ODE solution in forms other than exponential or as a pure function

Tags: differential-equations

I'm new to Mathematica and trying to solve some ODE's through it. But, whenever I try solving these ODE's I get pure functions as solutions with exponents only. Here's a pic for example.
[image]

Now, if I do this problem by hand the general solution I get is
[image].

Is there anyway in mathematica that I can get solutions like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ps. I do not know why you have $c$ in your solution, since you have initial condition there, so there should not be a constant of integration.  The solution you show by hand is general `implicit`. There is no option in `DSolve` to ask for an implicit solution. At least not directly.

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'[x] == (4*x + y[x] + 1)^2
ic = y[0] == 1;
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
ExpToTrig[sol] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be future version of `DSolve` will have `implicit' option. It will good to have.

In Maple, there is one. Here is an example

```
ode := diff(y(x),x) = (4*x + y(x) + 1)^2;
dsolve(ode,y(x),'implicit')
```

[image]

Just to clarify the implicit/explicit solutions. In Maple, it has an option to return either explicit or implicit. Ofcourse, the explicit solution is returned if $y(x)$ can be solved for in the first place, otherwise it will do like `DSolve` does when it can't solve for $y(x)$. The default is `explicit` like with `DSolve` now.

[image]

This is illustrated in this example by

[image]

It will be good if `DSolve` also had such an option to allow one to choose at user level.

Comment: Is there any other function in mathematica which could give me implicit solutions?

Comment: @AyushYadav Not that I know about. I asked about having an `implicit` option for `DSolve` myself before a few times. It will be nice to have.

Comment: Is there any other software/program/lang other than mathematica which could give implicit solutions?

Comment: @AyushYadav updated.

Comment: @Nasser Sometimes Mathematica shows some kind of implicit solution. Try to solve for `x[y]` : `DSolve[{1 == x'[y] (1 + 4 x[y] + y + 1)^2, x[1] == 0}, x[y], y]  ` and Mathematica retrurns an evaluated implicit expression `Solve[2 ArcTan[1/2 (2 + y + 4 x[y])] - 4 x[y] == 2 ArcTan[3/2], x[y]] `

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes, good point. But this happens when it "can't" solve it for $y(x)$. When it can, then it will return explicit solution and there is no way for the user to override this later behavior.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann fyi, I added more about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {y'[x] == (4 x + y[x] + 1)^2, y[0] == 1};
```

A pure function results from not providing an explicit argument to the function `y` in [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
sol1 = DSolve[eqn, y, x][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{x}, -(((-2 - I) + (1 + 2 I) E^(4 I x) - 4 I x + 
     4 E^(4 I x) x)/(-I + E^(4 I x)))]} *)
```

This form is useful when replacing the function `y` in expressions that may also include its derivatives. For example, to verify the solution:

```
eqn /. sol1 // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

However, to simplify the result, the pure function must be evaluated

```
sol2 = {y[x] -> (y[x] /. sol1) // ExpToTrig // FullSimplify}

(* {y[x] -> 1 - 4 x + 4/(-1 + Cot[2 x])} *)
```

In this form, replacing derivatives is somewhat more involved, particularly if high-order derivatives are involved.

```
eqn[[1]] /. {sol2[[1]], D[sol2[[1]], x]} // Simplify

(* True *)
```

With an explicit argument to the function in `DSolve`, the solution can be directly simplified

```
sol3 = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x][[1]] // ExpToTrig // FullSimplify

(* {y[x] -> 1 - 4 x + 4/(-1 + Cot[2 x])} *)

sol3 === sol2

(* True *)
```